# Amazon SES example for Delphi

Tags: delphi, amazon-ses

Anyone know of an example of using [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/de/ses/) with Delphi, or failing that, some tips to get me started?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need a Delphi TCP/IP library like Indy or Synapse, and send HTTP requests as shown in the Amazon SES [documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/ses/):

```
https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
?Action=SendEmail
&Source=user%40example.com
&Destination.ToAddresses.member.1=allan%40example.com
&Message.Subject.Data=This%20is%20the%20subject%20line.
&Message.Body.Text.Data=Hello.%20I%20hope%20you%20are%20having%20a%20good%20day.
```

Answer (score 0):

We have created a Delphi open source library for SES that might help you:

https://github.com/monde-sistemas/delphi-aws-ses